# How to insert new rows for each foreign key from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, exists

I want to make a query to add for each user all the id_job, id_role pairs from the user with id 0 (id_user, default user). Is it possible in mysql?

**user_role** table

| id_user | id_job | id_role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |

These are the dates I want to get to. As you can see in the first table, for the user with id 2, we don't have id_job and id_role [(1,1), (2,2)] and I want to run a query that populates the missing pairs for this user.

**user_role_updated** table

| id_user | id_job | id_role |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 |
| **2** | **1** | **1** |
| **2** | **2** | **2** |

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into user_role(id_user, id_job, id_role)
with cte_0 as(select id_user
                     , id_job
                     , id_role 
              from user_role 
              where id_user = 0)
select distinct ur.id_user
                , cte_0.id_job
                , cte_0.id_role
from user_role ur
     , cte_0
where ur.id_user <> 0
and (ur.id_user, cte_0.id_job, cte_0.id_role) not in (select id_user, id_job, id_role from user_role where id_user <> 0)
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=baad2b038059eb3005cad0a14e6f2558)